# Javascript syntax highlight for *.js.twig files in PhpStorm 5

Tags: ide, twig, phpstorm

What should I do to make PhpStorm to highlight javascript syntax in *.js.twig files as it highlights *.js files and at the same time twig tags and constructions.

Comment: Did you try to specify JavaScript as the [template data language](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/specifying-template-data-languages-for-templates.html) for these files?

Comment: Wow! That is the answer! Thank you! Is there way to set template data language automatically for all *.js.twig files?

Comment: Yes, [check this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/determining-template-data-language-by-a-file-extension/).

Comment: I've checked this post already, but there is IntelliJ IDEA case is considered. I've checked PHPStorm 5 Settings -> File Types -> Twig but didn't find Template Data Language item (only wildcard item). Maybe this feature was integrated in PhpStorm 6. Do you know?

Comment: It looks like configuration has changed since IDEA 9 and now you can't do it any more.

Answer (score -1):

Open settings panel (in Files > Settings...), then choose 'File Types' under 'IDE Settings' in the left menu. In the right menu choose 'Javascript file' under 'Recognized File Types' and click '+' under 'Registered Patterns'. Enter '*.js.twig' and click 'OK'.

Comment: The right answer was given by @CrazyCoder in the comment to the question.

Comment: This will highlight the javascript correctly but it will also show errors on twig tags used in those files.